# JSON Schema for collections

Tags: jsonschema, raml

I am looking for how to write a JSON schema for collection of objects within an object.

```json
{
    "name": "Sadiq",
    "age": 68,
    "email": [
        {
            "emailid": "sadiq@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "emailid": "sadiq@yahoo.com"
        }
    ],
    "phone": [
        {
            "phonenumber": "301-215-8006"
        },
        {
            "phonenumber": "301-215-8007"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible way to write this schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "required": true
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "emailid": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "phone": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "phonenumber": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Possible improvements would be:

- Add a regex pattern to strongly validate the `emailid` field
- Extract `email` and `phone` into top level types and refer to them in the above schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try of [csonschema](http://csonschema.org), which let you write jsonschema with a more easier way.

```
name: 'string'
age: 'integer'
email: ['email']
phone: ['string']
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is json library which can help you encode or reformat as u need